# Dynamically setting DataGrid Columns to ComboBox Columns via data-binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid binded to a DataTable that I've called "GridCollection" :

```
<!--DataGrid-->
    <DataGrid Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding GridCollection}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectionOptions}">
                                <ComboBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Caption, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="ShowComboBox">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </ComboBox.Style>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I want to be able to dynamically update the DataGrid Column Cell Template to display comboboxes.

I've tried to achieve this by adding a DataTrigger binded to a property of the DataTable column ("Caption"), and then updating the Visibility of the combobox accordingly.

My understanding is that the DataContext in this case is the DataTable's Columns.

I have tried setting the "Caption" property of the DataTable's Columns to match the value speicified in the DataTrigger ("ShowComboBox") :

```
ViewModel.GridCollection.Columns[index].Caption = "ShowComboBox";
```

After confirming that this line of code is being executed and that the Caption property is being updated, this is still making no change to the DataGrid. No columns are showing a combo box.

I'm not sure if there is a problem with the binding, or if it is something else.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `DataColumn` doesn't implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and raise property change notifications to WPF, this won't work.

If you however add a column to the `DataTable` and bind to this one, it will work:

```
ViewModel.GridCollection.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Caption"));
```

The difference is that the `DataRowView` class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. This is required for WPF to be able to listen to changes to a source property and update the view dynamically.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed DataColumn implemented INotifyPropertyChanged since the rest of the DataGrid is updating properly. Seems like DataTable at least implements it... The issue I'm having is that the column names are read in from file, and there's no way to know which ones need to be combo box columns until run-time. Is there any way I could write this binding in the XAML without knowing the column's name or index?

Comment: Why binding are you referring to? Which part of it is dynamic? Can't you just add a Caption column dynamically as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: The Column headers are dynamic (really, the entire table is read in from file). "Caption" in my code, is a property of an individual DataColumn, not the Column's header name. I need to bind to a property of a DataColumn. That is the binding I'm referring to.

Comment: As already metioned, you cannot bind to a property of the DataColumn but you can bind to a column itself. And these are dynamic. So I don't really understand your issue.

Comment: I can set the visibility of a combobox by binding to an entire column? What triggers the change in visibility if I can't use a property?

Comment: A cell rather. Set the Caption of the row for which you want to display a ComboBox to "ShowComboBox" and stick with your existing XAML.

Comment: There is no Caption property for DataRows or cells.

Comment: That's my point....you need to add a column named "Caption". Didn't you read my answer? I even included a code sample on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Yes, I do understand how to add a column named "Caption" to my table, and I understand that I could bind to said column. That, however, does not allow me to display combo boxes in existing columns/cells in my DataTable, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, it does. You set the Caption column of the row on which you want to display a ComboBox to "ShowComboBox". A DataGrid displays all rows of the DataTable and your XAML binds to a cell/column value of a particular row.

Comment: Thank you. This did work to display a combo box in the first column. I'm still trying to figure out how to get it to display the combo box in existing columns. I've updated the question to show the output I'm getting.

Comment: The rest of the columns? You have only defined one column, haven't you?

Comment: No columns have been defined in the XAML, but there are many in my DataTable, in addition to the "Caption" column added solely for the purpose of updating the visibility of the comboboxes in the other columns.

Comment: The cell template doesn't seem to have any effect on the columns that were added via my datatable.

Comment: Of course not...you have only applied the template to the ComboBox in the column that you have defined explicitly in your XAML so your last question doesn't make much sense I am afraid.  But please ask a new question if you have another issue. I believe that your original question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the layout you need to reset your binding.
Remove the binding / data source from you datagrid. Change the Caption value and bind the source again to your datagrid.

Here the code which works for me:

The XAML of the window

```
Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="grd" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="01" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="02" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CBX">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox>
                            <ComboBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Caption, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="ShowCombobox">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ComboBox.Style>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        items soureitems = new items();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            item sourceitem = new item();
            sourceitem.Name = "John";
            sourceitem.LastName = "Doe";
            sourceitem.Caption = "";
            soureitems.Add(sourceitem);
        }

        this.DataContext = soureitems;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        items sourceitems = (items)(this.DataContext);
        this.DataContext = null;
        foreach (item sourceitem in sourceitems)
        {
            if(sourceitem.Caption != "ShowCombobox")
            {
                sourceitem.Caption = "ShowCombobox";
            } else
            {
                sourceitem.Caption = "";
            }
        }
        this.DataContext = sourceitems;
    }
}

public class items : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<item> { }

public class item
{
    string _Name;
    string _LastName;
    string _Caption;
    public string Name {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _LastName; }
        set { _LastName = value; }
    }
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return _Caption; }
        set { _Caption = value; }
    }
}
}
```